# How to localize/change DataAnnotation's Required field validator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, requiredfieldvalidator

How can I localize/change DataAnnotations Required field validator and other resource parameters?

RequiredAttribute_ValidationError has value "The {0} field is required" in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these properties to override the default error message for the `Required` attribute [ErrorMessageResourceName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
[ErrorMessageResourceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="MyLocalizedResourceName", ErrorMessageResourceType="MyLocalizedResourceType")]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Have you any example?

Comment: `[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName= "FullNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResource)]`  Just add a resource file (*.resx) and make an entry in it.  Standard localization procedures.  There are plenty of *.resx based localization examples floating around.

Comment: how can I localize without defining ErrorMessageResourceName, ErrorMessageResourceType?

Comment: you can't. Those are the properties the `Required` attribute expects to know which localized resource to load.

Comment: Thanks mckeejm! I solved my problem that way, which you advice by indicating ResourceName, ResourceType properties.

Comment: please accept the answer so that others may find it useful as well

Comment: MCkeejm - can you answer to my other question on this URL:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700102/how-to-locally-save-model-object-on-mvc-4