# How to locally save model object on MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a model on MVC project and suitable xml document , which gets from web service and it will be deserialized with type of my model. And I will get deserialized object and work with it. How to save locally changes in this model object?

Answer (score 0):

The design of your persistence layer depends alot on the purpose of your applciation, and the lifetime of the objects persisted.  A [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solution would provide a simple way to serialize/deserialize objects  your application. MVC 4 pushes [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)as its "Code-First" option for persisting objects into a SQL Server backed data store. Entity Framework has plenty of tutorials at the link I shared.

Comment: Thanks for response! 
Firstly i get xml document and deserialize to my model class.
Secondly i will work with this deserialized object and i have to save any chnages from client side somewhere (But i do not know where).
And the end of all changes i have to serialize this object to xml and send by web service. 
How can I realize this idea?

Comment: yeah i picked up on that.. I would take a look at Entity Framework and see if it meets your needs.  That's the Microsoft recommended (because  it's their product) solution.

Comment: Did you find the way of saving locally?

Comment: it's in the tutorials.. just go check them out

Comment: I did not find anywhere. Can you give some posts, links?